# C++ delete[] crashes

Tags: c++, arrays, string, delete-operator

I'm writing a C++ program, that stores strings in a string array, when the array is full I resize the array to make space for more items using the code below. But sometimes (not always) it crashes at the "delete[] temp;" line and I don't know why and how to fix it. Please, help.

I have searched a lot but could not find an answer anywhere. When I debug it says "invalid pointer" but how can it be invalid when I stored data there before and did not free it yet?

This is my code:

```
if(item_cnt >= (arr_size - 1))
{
    int oldsize = arr_size;
    string * temp;
    arr_size *= 2;
    temp = arr;
    arr = new string [arr_size];
    memcpy(arr, temp, oldsize * sizeof(temp));
    delete[] temp;
}
```

Comment: Some points of style: You should be using `std::copy`, not `memcpy`.  And you shouldn't be doing manual memory management (`new`, `delete`, etc.), you should be using a container class to handle this all automatically.

Comment: `memcpy(arr, temp, oldsize * sizeof(temp));` -- Shouldn't that be `sizeof(*temp)`? (yes, though of course, the memcpy is wrong to begin with)

Comment: This is bad... Don't use memcpy on strings. Use `string myString (toBeCopied);` .. see here: http://anaturb.net/C/string_exapm.htm

Comment: Well, thank you for alerting me on what is wrong about my code, I will keep it on my mind (I am not being sarcastic, I really am glad). But neither of these explains the crash on delete[]. Does anyone know why it behaves like that?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you absolutely have to stick with your current approach, I would recommend using a vector to hold your strings. It will manage all the memory for you.

Here's an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> arrayOfStrings;

   arrayOfStrings.push_back("Hello World!"); // To Add Items
   string value = arrayOfString.at(<some index>); // To Retrieve an Item you can also use the [] operator instead of the at method

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: if for some reason you need to point to an array, you could still use the vector and pass `&arrayOfStrings[0]` where you need a pointer.

Comment: Actually, it is my homework (yes, I know it might be called cheating, but I really couldn't find the reason for the behavior I described) and I am not allowed to use vectors here. But thanks for the tip anyways

Answer (score 1):

The `memcpy` is at the root of your problem. everyone's said "don't use it", but let me explain exactly why it's a terminally bad idea.

First off, what is a c++ string, and how does it do its magic? It's basically a variable-length array of characters, and it achieves this feat by holding a pointer within each string object that points to the memory allocated to hold those characters. As the string grows or shrinks, that memory gets reallocated. Copy strings *properly* involves making a 'deep copy' of the contents.

Now, to your code:

```
arr = new string [arr_size];
```

This creates an array of empty string objects. Because they're empty, the internal pointers are typically null.

```
memcpy(arr, temp, oldsize * sizeof(temp));
```

Here, bad things happen. This isn't actually creating copies of the original strings, it's just overwriting the internal representation. So both the old and the new strings 'point'  to the same character data. Now to *really* screw things up, this happens:

```
delete[] temp;
```

We delete thew old strings, but this also frees up the character memory that they were using. So our 'new' copies of these strings are pointing at memory that's actually been freed. We now have a car-crash waiting to happen : The character data could be re-used for anything, and when we try and delete the strings again, the operating system will hopefully spot that you're trying to free memory that hasn't been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Your array should be really

```
vector<string>
```

This is a recommended way of implementing arrays of dynamic size. By using vector you avoid necessity to reallocate/copy stuff manually and avoid problems like the one you have altogether.

Comment: why? An explanation would help.

Answer (score -1):

Mixing old style and new style memory operations is always a bad idea... here you use `memcpy` and `new`/ `delete`. be aware that `delete[]` also calls the dtor for each element of the array...

Edit:
ctor --> dtor

hth

Mario